SSO Component return bad request after a day
I am using the following copilot studio sample
SharePointSSOComponent
When I install it on site, it works. But, after some period of time (e.g one day), it stops working and the bot it keeps loading. The code error is 400 bad request.
Ιt says that it receives bad request on oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint. The important note is that If I uninstall the app from the site contents and install it again, then it works again. After one day it stops working again. It is like something expires every x amount of time.

How can i refresh the token before expired ? Any other solution or idea ?

Here are a few potential causes and solutions for the 400 Bad Request error that occurs after a day:

Token Expiry: Ensure that your authentication tokens are being
refreshed properly. If the token expires after a day, it could lead
to a 400 error.

Data Limits: Copilot Studio limits connector responses to 500
KB. If your request returns too much data, it might cause a 400
error. Try filtering the data to reduce the response size.

Configuration Issues: Double-check your SSO and connector
configurations. Any misconfiguration could lead to authentication
errors.

Network Issues: Intermittent network issues can also cause 400
errors. Ensure your network connection is stable and there are no
firewall rules blocking the requests.


